# How to setup menu data in Context_processor in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-context

I have `category` and `subcategory` store in my database, and `subcategory` is related to `category`, I have multiple pages on my website, but I am able to display category in the menu on some pages, but I want to display on all pages, so I found the solution using context_processor, but I am unable to render HTML file there, it only takes data in the dictionary file, please check my code and let me know where I am mistaking.

here is my `models.py` file...

```
class Category(models.Model):
   cat_name=models.CharField(max_length=225)
   cat_slug=models.SlugField(max_length=225, unique=True)
   
   def __str__(self):
   return self.cat_name

class SubCategory(models.Model):
   subcat_name=models.CharField(max_length=225)
   subcat_slug=models.SlugField(max_length=225, unique=True)
   category = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='subcategoryies', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
  
   def __str__(self):
   return self.subcat_name
```

here is my `context_processor.py` file...

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from dashboard.models import Category, SubCategory

def context_categories(request, cat_slug):
    category = Category.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
    return render(request, "base.html", {'category':category})
```

included this file in `settings.py` file under `TEMPLATES` section

```
 'mainpage.context_processors.context_categories',
```

here is my `base.html` file...

```
{% for cat in category %}
      <li>
       <a href="javascript:void()">{{cat.cat_name}}</a>
          <ul>
           {% for subcat in cat.subcategoryies.all %}
            <li><a href="/subcategory/{{subcat.subcat_slug}}">{{subcat.subcat_name}}</a></li>
             {% endfor %}
           </ul>
       </li>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: A contextprocessor only passes extra variables to the template render engine, so it returns a dictionary, and does not take any parameters (except for the request).

Comment: The [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) is a much better way to realize its