# Template used by multiple apps requires a specific variable

Tags: python, django, django-templates

When one uses a template, used by various apps, that requires a specific variable

```
<a href="{% url 'blog:blog-detail' user_blog %}">My blog</a>
```

we want to ensure that the template will always be aware of the variable `user_blog`. Also, we don't want to hammer the logic in every view.

In such cases, the question popping up is usually within the lines of ["How to make a variable available to all templates?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17901341/5675325) and so we are redirected to [Template context processors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17901516/5675325).

---

Since what we want is dependent on a user instance, we wouldn't be able to use a context processor for something like this

```
user_blog = self.request.user.blog
return {'user_blog': user_blog}
```

because, as noted by [Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63113281/how-to-setup-menu-data-in-context-processor-in-django#comment111605169_63113281)

> A contextprocessor only passes extra variables to the template render engine, so it returns a dictionary, and does not take any parameters (except for the request).

What do we then do in such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A context processor actually had access to the request object:

```py
# context_processors.py
def getBlog(request):
    return { 'user_blog': request.user.blog }
```

**But!** request.user is already available from inside the template, so you don't need a context processor.

---

But if request.user -> blog isn't a direct connection you could do something like:

- **Note:** More-so just showing it's possible

```py
# context_processors.py
def getBlog(request):
    from myproject.thing.models import Blog
    return { 'user_blog': Blog.objects.filter(user=request.user).first() }
```

The better route (so you're not always hitting the DB on *every* request) is to add a cache:

```py
# context_processors.py
def getBlog(request):

    from django.core.cache import cache

    cachedname = 'UserBlog:{0}'.format(request.user.username)
    cachedData = cache.get(cachedname)

    if cachedData:
        # in cache (yay!)
        return { 'user_blog': cachedData }

    else:
        # not in cache (boo!) 

        from myproject.thing.models import Blog
        user_blog = Blog.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()

        cache.set(cachedname, user_blog, 600) # 10 minute cache

        return { 'user_blog': user_blog }
```

Answer (score 1):

In such case you don't really need to use Template Context Processors.

You can simply do the following in the template

```
<a href="{% url 'blog:blog-detail' request.user.blog %}">>My blog</a>
```

Needless to say you ought to check if `request.user.blog` exists or not.